# Handling large data set

Tags: c#, visual-studio, neural-network, kinect, bigdata

I'm developing an application to capture human emotions using kinect device. Therefore I captured 6 action unit values for one emotion from 8 person and 30 frames for each. So now I have a lot of data and I want to identify emotions based on this data (note that each emotion have different action values for each action unit).

So far I developed my application based Visual Studio and SQL Server. I would like if anyone can suggest me a better approach to use these data and predict emotion using new frame action unit values and it is better if I can do it with C# and Visual Studio.

Here is a snap of my dataset I captured:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the goal, it is a typical classification task. So initially we have finite set of classes (emotions). All we want is to find the class (emotion) based on input data (action unit values). 
The most obvious way is to create [artificial neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), train it with subset of data, and then test with the rest part of it.
You can use any neural network library for C#, or implement by yourself.
 See example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16447/Neural-Networks-on-C).
There also another algorithms of classification covered [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep521/07wi/prj/leonardo_fabricio.pdf), that do not use neural networks.

Comment: thank you for the response. I too thought of going for a neural network to classification. Could you please suggest me a basic guide or tutorial series to learn and build the application.

Comment: It you're using C#, then you can start [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36428.basis-of-neural-networks-in-c.aspx)